# Should we create separate login activity to login in app?

Tags: android

Need Suggestions.

I was discussing the design of an android app. Should we create a login activity to let a user login to the app or should we redirect the user to a browser and let him login over there and then on successful login redirect him back to the app and may be a next activity.

So I want to know that what are the benefits and consequences of doing it the either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either way, but like most apps do, **I would suggest a login activity** instead of browser redirect.
Browser redirect is just an overkill, for the user, as well as for the developer.

First of all, even if you use the in-app webview which doesn't make the user open the browser, it still means that the whole HTML will be loaded, which would take time and also consume data.

It's generally more user friendly if you use a Login activity. This ensures that:

1. The user doesn't have to wait for the page to load. The whole page is in memory. You can take the data required to login from the user in the activity itself.
2. You do not have to write code to handle the redirect. I know it isn't much of a challenge, but still, why complicate matters?
3. You can make any service calls you need in the activity itself, display appropriate error or success messages in a customised beautiful way like you want (which is the point of an app), and can start following a theme for the rest of the app, which makes the user comfortable with the app.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for quick Response..! but I would like to discuss the Forget Password scenario.How can we handle that without using in-app browser concept and also apart from that does it make any security threat if I use the login activity instead of redirecting it to browser

Comment: You can add the same implementation of the Forget password scenario in your app as you have done in in your website. Get the request for the id for which the user has forgotten the password, make a service call, and take the action (reset password link on email, otp etc; whichever one is applicable). There are no security threats, as long as you're using auth in your service calls, as far as I know.
However, like I said, avoid getting the new password in the app itself, if it worries you. Set up the generation of new password via a reset password link emailed to the user.